# Version control for objects in R workspace?

Tags: r, oop, version-control

At a minimum I would like to document objects in the R workspace - when they were created and/or when they were last updated. Even better, it would be great to document any executed code that modifies an object. Is there any package or environment that does this? One thought is to update the operator `<-` with something like

```
`%setto%` <- function(a, b) {
  list(
    b,
    'time' = Sys.time(),
    'history' = enquote(b)
  )
}
```

with output like:

```
> hat %setto% rev(1:10)
[[1]]
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1

$time
[1] "2023-05-11 08:15:18 PDT"

$history
base::quote(10:1)
```

But obviously this is shortsighted and doesn't handle objects modified by `load` etc. Has this been attempted with any level of success?

Comment: Its intent is more to speed up/cache data, but it has data lineage/dependency tracing that might be useful. Check out the targets package: https://docs.ropensci.org/targets/index.html